# Extra output when writing to file using std::cout

Tags: c++, std, cin, cout, freopen

I am trying to read data from a file `in.txt`, and after some computations, I am writing the output to `out.txt`

***Why is there an extra 7 at the end of `out.txt`?***

#### Contents of `Solution` class.

```cpp
class Solution
{
public:
    int findComplement(int num)
    {
        int powerof2 = 2, temp = num;

        /*
        get number of bits corresponding to the number, and
        find the smallest power of 2 greater than the number.
        */
        while (temp >> 1)
        {
            temp >>= 1;
            powerof2 <<= 1;
        }

        // subtract the number from powerof2 -1
        return powerof2 - 1 - num;
    }
};
```

#### Contents of `main` function.

Assume all headers are included. `findComplement` flips bits of a number. For example, The integer 5 is "101" in binary and its complement is "010" which is the integer 2.

```cpp
int main() {

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif

    // helper variables
    Solution answer;
    int testcase;

    // read input file, compute answer, and write to output file
    while (std::cin) {
        std::cin >> testcase;
        std::cout << answer.findComplement(testcase) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Contents of `in.txt`

```
5
1
1000
120
```

#### Contents of `out.txt`

```
2
0
23
7
7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason there is an extra 7 is that your loop executes one too many times. You need to check `std::cin` *after* you've tried to read the input.

As is, you simply repeat the last test case.

Comment: Oh, I see. `while (std::cin && std::cin >> value)` did the trick. I didn't understand it completely though. Does this mean - if  "there is input at stdin" and "the input is valid", do something?

Comment: @AdityaWagh You can write this as `while (std::cin >> value)`. You can "translate" this as "try to extract a value, execute the body of the loop if there was no error in extraction".

Comment: Thanks! That clears it. Have a nice day!